# count non-null elements of IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, count, ienumerable, httppostedfilebase

I have a view model in asp .net mvc 3 which has

```
IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files
```

In the view, I have a for loop that creates 9 input tags for these files.

I want to implement a check on the server-side to ensure atleast 3 files are being uploaded.

I tried putting a condition

```
if(files.Count() > 2) { // code here }
```

However, that returns 9 as it also counts the null elements.

I can think of implementing a counter myself as below:

```
int count = 0;
@foreach(var file in files) {
  if(file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) { 
    count++; 
  }
}
```

Is this the best way to do this or is there a functionality already in asp .net mvc for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
files.Count(file=>file != null && file.ContentLength > 0);
```

Comment: @Tripping No, I won't be worse that your loop(I don't mean it is bad.)

Comment: Should I use a list and length instead? I am very new to asp .net or web development in general and was reading that using count is not a good idea. Many Thanks

Comment: @Tripping Before thinking micro optimizations, try to write a readable/maintainable code. When you check null and ContentLength you will have to loop through the list and Linq won't be slower.

Comment: @Tripping Do you have a few hundred thousand (or million) items in your list, or are you performing this operation a few hundred thousand times?  If so, there may be a preferable way (you could use `Skip` and `Any()` to short circuit the operation and end early) but odds are your code is more than fast enough even with a naive algorithm.

Comment: Why don't you change your model to `List<HttpPostedFileBase>` and call `.Count` property on it

Comment: @IliaG Because he's not counting every item, he's counting just the items that meet certain criteria.

Comment: @Servy I get that, but he can filter them once in the controller and work with filtered list inside the view.

Answer (score 4):

Use a predicate to filter the count:

```
files.Where(file => file != null).Count()
```

Or simpler, just `files.Count(file => file != null)`.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you see the paradigm of `enumerable.Count() > X` you could use the following method which gives you the benefit of ending as soon as you know you have enough items:

```
public static bool HasAtLeast<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int number)
{
    return source.Skip(number - 1).Any();
}
```

Given that method you could write:

```
if(files.Where(file => file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    .HasAtLeast(2))
{
    //code goes here
}
```

Now, is this a major improvement, no, probably not.  You'd need to either be executing this code many, many thousands of times, have a gigantic enumeration, or have an enumeration that is expensive to enumerate (if it's the result of a LINQ query performing long running methods for example) for it to matter.  If you didn't put `HasAtLeast` into it's own method it would also decrease readability, so that alone wouldn't be worth the (usually small) performance advantage.